# how to check on 30 label control with a condition vb.net

Tags: vb.net, loops, label, controls

I have 30 labels, and 1 label is the header. IF I click on ANY of the 30 labels that changes its forecolor to red THEN will also make the header forecolor red. BUT IF ALL of the labels forecolor is black THEN the header label forecolor will also be black. How do you make a condition without having to type each label in the IF..THEN.ELSE command. Im using vb.net window controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your labels are all in the same container control(like `Form`, `Panel`, etc), you can use `parent.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()`, for example:

```
Dim allButHeader = From lbl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
                   Where lbl.Name <> "HeaderLabelName"
For Each lbl As Label In allButHeader
    lbl.ForeColor = Color.Red
Next
```

I have used the label's name to identify the header, but you can use a different way to exclude it.

**Edit** according to your comment:

> Lets assume the labels turns red or black when you click which is
>   already coded using the "For Each lbl As Label...." My question is how
>   to check if ANY of the label is red THEN the header turns red ELSE IF
>   ALL the labels are black then the header will be black.

Simple with LINQ:

```
Dim labels = Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
Dim header = labels.First(Function(lbl) lbl.Name = "HeaderLabelName")
Dim allButHeader = From lbl In labels
                   Where lbl.Name <> "HeaderLabelName"
Dim anyRed = allButHeader.Any(Function(lbl) lbl.ForeColor = Color.Red)
If anyRed Then
    header.ForeColor = Color.Red
Else
    Dim allBlack = allButHeader.All(Function(lbl) lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black)
    If allBlack Then
        header.ForeColor = Color.Black
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. But the code makes all my label red except for the header. Lets assume the labels turns red or black when you click which is already coded using the "For Each lbl As Label...." My question is how to check if ANY of the label is red THEN the header turns red ELSE IF ALL the labels are black then the header will be black.

Comment: Thanks Tim is there a way to do this without having to use LINQ?

Comment: LINQ is basically a readable version of loops. So just iterate the Controls collection and fill a List(Of Label). Use typeof(control) to Check if its a Label.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is in one line inside the event handler, but this is a complete solution

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each l As Label In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)().Where(Function(lbl) lbl.Name <> "HeaderLabel")
        AddHandler l.Click, AddressOf colorLabels
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub colorLabels(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim myLabel = CType(sender, Label)
    ' toggle the label color
    myLabel.ForeColor = If(myLabel.ForeColor = Color.Black, Color.Red, Color.Black)
    ' the logic to handle the header
    Me.HeaderLabel.ForeColor = If(Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label).
            Where(Function(lbl) lbl.Name <> "HeaderLabel").
            Select(Of Color)(Function(lbl) lbl.ForeColor).
            Aggregate(Of Boolean)(True, Function(last As Boolean, clr As Color) last And (clr = Color.Black)), Color.Black, Color.Red)
End Sub
```